# How should I test my actions which updates state in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-testing-library, vitest

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "../src/store/store";
import Navbar from "../src/layout/Navbar";

describe("Navbar Component", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Navbar />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    });

    describe("Hamburger Icon", () => {
        let hamburger;

        beforeEach(() => {
            hamburger = screen.getByTestId("hamburger");
        });

        it("should render the icon properly", () => {
            expect(hamburger).toBeInTheDocument();
        });

        it("should close sidebar on click event", async () => {
            const hamburger = screen.getByTestId("hamburger");
            expect(store.getState().app.isSideBarVisible).toBe(true);
            fireEvent.click(hamburger);
            expect(store.getState().app.isSideBarVisible).toBe(false);
        });

        it("should open the sidebar on click event", () => {
            const hamburger = screen.getByTestId("hamburger");
            expect(store.getState().app.isSideBarVisible).toBe(false);
            fireEvent.click(hamburger);
            expect(store.getState().app.isSideBarVisible).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

How to test such actions, like after I click something, changes in my Redux store properly. I'm new to writing tests; point me to the best way to handle this.

And how to test things in frontend more efficiently to get better with this, like do we need to test everything, such as state updates and the complete user journey, or just the component rendering and props, like the basic ones, and also how to test such things, like if in useEffect I'm calling async fetch functions and if they are updating the state properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to test that your actions update the store correctly then the unit test should work directly with your state reducers.

Example state slice and unit test:

app.slice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const initialState = {
  isSideBarVisible: false,
};

const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'app',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleSidebar: (state) => {
      state.isSideBarVisible = !state.isSideBarVisible;
    },
  },
});

export const actions = { ...appSlice.actions };

export default appSlice.reducer;
```

app.slice.test.js

```js
import reducer, { actions, initialState } from './app.slice';

describe('app slice', () => {
  it('should have initial app state', () => {
    expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual(initialState);
  });

  it('should toggle sidebar visibility', () => {
    expect(reducer(actions.toggleSidebar(), { isSideBarVisible: false }))
      .toEqual({ isSideBarVisible: true });

    expect(reducer(actions.toggleSidebar(), { isSideBarVisible: true }))
      .toEqual({ isSideBarVisible: false });

  });
});
```

The unit test for your `Navbar` component using React-Testing-Library (RTL) should not concern itself with internal implementation details as this goes against RTL's testing methodology. You should test the UI via its APIs, the same way users and other components interact with it, e.g. via it's props or rendered UI.

If you want to unit test `Navbar`'s hamburger menu button then a test case may look similar to the following.

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "../src/store/store";

export const Providers = ({ children }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {children}
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Providers } from "../path/to/Providers";
import Navbar from "../src/layout/Navbar";

describe("Navbar Component", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<Navbar />, { wrapper: Providers });
  });

  describe("Hamburger Icon", () => {
    let hamburger;

    beforeEach(() => {
      hamburger = screen.getByTestId("hamburger");
    });

    it("should render the icon properly", () => {
      expect(hamburger).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it("should toggle hamburger menu on click", async () => {
      const hamburger = screen.getByTestId("hamburger");

      // Starts closed
      expect(screen./* get/query something in UI */)./* assertion closed */;

      // Click to open menu and assert menu is open
      fireEvent.click(hamburger);
      expect(screen./* get/query something in UI */)./* assertion open */;

      // Click to close menu and assert menu is closed
      fireEvent.click(hamburger);
      expect(screen./* get/query something in UI */)./* assertion closed */;
    });
  });

  ...
});
```